# Reset Password Help

Tags: joomla-3.5

In what table is the token to reset a password saved? How is the token generated?

Answer (score 4):

The password reset procedure happens in the following model

```
components\com_users\models\reset.php
```

The token is generated by the following code just prior to the email being sent to the user:

```
// Set the confirmation token.
    $token = JApplicationHelper::getHash(JUserHelper::genRandomPassword());
    $hashedToken = JUserHelper::hashPassword($token);

    $user->activation = $hashedToken;
```

As you can probably tell from the fuction names, this generates a random password and saves it as a secure hash in the activation field of the `users` table.

When the user resets their password, various checks are run, but this is the one that tests that the token matches the one the user has just entered.

```
if (empty($user) || $user->activation !== $token)
        {
            $this->setError(JText::_('COM_USERS_USER_NOT_FOUND'));

            return false;
        }
```